# Getting 3NF from MINIMAL COVER

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-schema, database-normalization, 3nf

Schema attributes: A,B,C,D,E,F,G

The candidate keys of the schema are A, CF, BFG

Now I have a following minimal cover:

BG->C, ABG->D CF->A A->C A->G AD->F AD->E AC->B

How can I get a 3NF decomposition from minimal cover?

Someone said just combine FDs with same left hand side, but it seems to be not totally right...

What is the standard process to do this?

Comment: "Someone said" does not constitute "show any research effort"--see [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. Dumps of requirements are not on-topic questions. Show the steps of your work following your textbook with justification & explain re the first place you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Any `R` relational schema* can be decomposed into multiple relations in 3NF form, given any set of dependencies on `R`.

If you have the following `G` minimal cover:

```
G = { X1 -> A1, X2 -> A2, ..., Xn ->An}
```

A correct 3NF, loseless, dependency preserving decomposition can be the following:

`r = {X1A1, X2A2, ..., XnAn} U {K}` where `K` is a key of the `R` relation.

The `r` decomposition preserves the original dependencies, because each dependency projected on the decomposed parts gives you one from the original set of dependencies in the `G` set.

The `r` decomposition also results in 3NF relations.

1; `K` is only needed for the lossless decomposition. If you need only dependency preserving, you don't have to add it.

2; During construction of `r` decomposition, it is possible that some `Ri` part of r contains a key of the original `R` relation. This time you don't have to add the plus schema with the key, since the key is already included in the decomposition.

*:Must be at least 1NF form, so the attributes are atomic.

**Example for your schema and set of dependencies**

Set of dependencies:

```
BG->C, ABG->D, CF->A, A->C, A->G, AD->F, AD->E, AC->B
```

Set of candidate keys:

```
A, CF, BFG
```

A lossless, dependency preserving 3NF Decomposition:

```
BGC, ABGD, CFA, AC, AG, ADF, ADE, ACB
```

As you can see A key is already included in the decomposition so you don't have to add that.

Comment: However, BFG is not in the decomposition. Do we have to add BFG in to the decomposition?

Comment: As long as there is one candidate key exists in the decomposition, we don't have to add the candidate key?